# call Actionscript method from JS without loading SWF

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

Well yeah, it sounds funny, but all I want is to read the value of `Capabilities.version` to get  the right version of the Flash player? I have tried getting the version info from `swfObject` library, but it doesn't give the complete version info:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html

FP version info have 4 numbers: `major, minor, release and build`. I couldn't find an API which can give me all four on all browsers without loading SWF. Hence I am looking for help here.

Comment: Why not create a teeny tiny SWF just for this purpose?

Comment: I think I'll have to do that only, I was looking for a cleaner approach

Comment: You don't have to add a swf to a object with flash type to get the version of the plugin. You just need to add the object to the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWFObject has a detection function built into it and for the most part it is cross-browser capable.
The function name is getFlashPlayerVersion
It returns an object with 3 attributes major, minor,release

[EDIT]
SWFObject also has a function called testPlayerVersion.
I shortened it up for you but I think it gets what you want.

```
var o = createElement(OBJECT);
o.setAttribute("type", FLASH_MIME_TYPE);
alert( doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(o).GetVariable("$version") )
doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(o);
```

Remember this is not browser compliant.
Pretty sure you need to test for plugin or active x also.

Comment: I know that and that's why I mentioned it doesn't give full info. I need the build info as well.. for some bug with a specific release.

Comment: Release is the build info. Or am I missing something.

Comment: Found a much better test you might be able to add to http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleDetectFlash

Comment: Thanks the_asMan but I have already tried getFlashPlayerVersion. Everything gives me 3 numbers not fourth! Same does your link above. I'll rather have to go with creating my own swf itself.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted It works for the plugin but not for ActiveX so you are half way there.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to load flash to know what is the version of the player.
There for is JS.

http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html

Comment: Thanks but swfObject does the same thing, now I tend to believe that there is a technical limitation on getting the complete flash version from JS